# What test to use for measuring differences in distribution

Tags: r, statistical-significance, biostatistics

I have a dataset with a number of grid cells that overlap with a protected area. for each grid cell, the percent overlap with the protected area was calculated using Qgis. For example, one grid cell has a value of 27%, meaning that 27% of that grid cell is covered by the protected area. I also have 16 species of bats and I want to test if one species (Myodas) has a significantly higher or lower percent overlap compared to the other species. The NA´s means that the given species is not present in that grid cell.
I thought of using an Anova, but data is not normally distributed, so maybe a Kruskal Wallis test instead?

```
> str(DamMPO)
tibble [108 x 17] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ gridcells.nr: num [1:108] 642 645 676 677 711 712 724 725 746 747 ...
 $ pleaur      : num [1:108] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ barbar      : num [1:108] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ nycnoc      : num [1:108] 6.56 NA NA NA NA ...
 $ nyclei      : logi [1:108] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ eptser      : num [1:108] 6.56 18.26 17.75 0.06 6.82 ...
 $ eptnil      : num [1:108] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ myonat      : num [1:108] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ myobra      : num [1:108] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ myomys      : num [1:108] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ myodas      : num [1:108] NA NA 17.8 NA NA ...
 $ myodau      : num [1:108] 6.56 NA 17.75 NA 6.82 ...
 $ myobec      : num [1:108] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ vesmur      : num [1:108] NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ pipnat      : num [1:108] NA NA 17.8 NA NA ...
 $ pippip      : num [1:108] NA NA 17.8 NA NA ...
 $ pippyg      : num [1:108] NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Comment: Can you please share (a link to) the data, so we can experiment. If not, maybe some mockup data.

Comment: By deleting and reposting your question you are just making our readers repeat earlier comments.  Please edit the original instead.